# MinGW g++ extremly slow compiling

Tags: c++, vim, g++, mingw

I started using Vim for C++ competitive programming and i have a problem . For compiling i am using MinGW g++ compiler as in tutorials . Code compiles , but i have issue that , any program compiles and runs extremly slow . For example to compile and run next code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std ; 

int main()
{
 cout<<"Hello World"<<endl;
}
```

(simplest programm ever) It takes 6 to 8 seconds to compile and run .

In Vim itself i have this shortcut :

```
autocmd filetype cpp nnoremap <C-r> :w <bar> !g++ -std=c++14 -Wall % -o %:r && %:r.exe <cr>
```

Can you help me to findout why i am having such an issue . For instance William Lin ( competetive programmer also uses Vim and mine shortuc is similar to his , but his programs runs instantly ).

Comment: I have no idea, but it might help others help you if you can try just compiling or just running your program to see which of those two is causing the delay. I'm guessing it will be the compilation, but it would be nice to know for sure.

Comment: You automatically compile and run any code you type in your editor? O_O . Please do just the compile. What if one day you leave it on and you type `fork()` inside an unfinished loop and just then it compiles?

Comment: How powerful is your computer? What happens if you run compile command directly from commandline?

Comment: @Gillespie Same if i will compile and run it from cmd . I am using laptop . 8gb ddr4 , I7 7700 , 1050ti , i think it's powerful enough to run helloworld

Comment: Antivirus? Unclevirus?

Comment: What's taking most of the time? The compilation or the run?

Comment: So guys , thank you . I solved this by turning off antivirus . But can you say , what process i should add to safe files in antivirus , so it will not check . g++ ?

Comment: My advice is put your code tree on some folder tree in your hard drive and tell your AV to ignore the entire folder. For me on windows regardless of the PC I am (or how the storage is organized) on I create an X: drive that I use for my code projects and tell my AV to ignore the entire x:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an shame to say this , but problem was in Antivirus . As i think it slow downs process to check for some virus

Comment: If it's interesting , it was antivirus Avira

Comment: Interesting find. I use native GCC under WSL2 which I think is why it isn't bothered by anti-virus

Comment: Maybe you can set the location of MinGW as a folder exclusion in the antivirus.

Answer (score 0):

Basically william and most of other CPers use what's called precompiled header file, to fasten up the **compilation** time, not the **execution**.
To do that first go to your bits folder. I installed using msys2 so here's my path:

```
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\c++\12.1.0\x86_64-w64-mingw32\bits
```

when you go inside this folder, you will se one file named `stdc++.h`. That is the file which gets compiled everytime you inculde `bits/stdc++.h` in the source code.
Compilation time is increased because it also inculdes some unnecessary headers which are generally not used. But for the sake of readability and short code, programmers generally include this file.

**Now** to precompile this file open your terminal in the same folder as bits or in windows you can click address bar and type cmd and press enter to open up the command prompt in the same folder.

After that run the following command `g++ stdc++.h -std=c++17`. Though you can change c++17 part to whatever you like (14 or 20) I recommend using c++17 because it is supported by most of the new online judges and is generally used. You will see one `stdc++.gch` file created in you folder which will be of a large size(~93 MB for c++17 and ~103 MB for c++20).

Now whenever you will compile your file. It would not take much longer.